# What is the max value of the 'Fixed' data type?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm reading one book about shaders and in one of the tutorials inside it I saw the following:

```
Properties 
     {
         _ScrollXSpeed ("X Scroll Speed", Range(0, 10)) = 3
         _ScrollYSpeed ("Y Scroll Speed", Range(0, 10)) = 3
     }

SubShader 
     {
         ...
         fixed _ScrollXSpeed;
         fixed _ScrollYSpeed;
         ...
     }
```

But the [unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-DataTypesAndPrecision.html) tells me the following:

> fixed
>
> Lowest precision fixed point value. Generally 11 bits, with a
>   range of –2.0 to +2.0 and 1/256th precision.

If the range of fixed is -2.0 to +2.0 how can I pass 10 to _ScrollXSpeed without an overflow? I tested the shader that uses these parameters and the variable is never capped at 2.

Comment: This range is probably for fractional part as it talks about precision. but max value is 11 bit so try a number greater than greatest 11bit number

Comment: @Umair 256 precision already uses 8 bits. Probably the last 3 are used for sign (1) and the other 2 for the actual value (which is a bit strange, because 2 bits = 4, not 2).